# Refinery Image Uploading giving no route match (How do you change default image route in refinery?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, refinerycms, broken-links, refinery

When uploading an image to the Refinery CMS I get a broken link.

```
No route matches [GET] "/system/images/W1siZiIsIjIwMTMvMDUvMDgvMjFfMjBfMjFfMzlfc3RlYWtfZmluYWwuanBnIl1d/steak-final.jpg"
```

Any idea why could this be happening or is there a fix?

UPDATE: The problem is that I am mounting Refinery on "/cms" instead of the root path.
But I still don't know how to change the picture route. If I add:

```
/cms
```

in front of the image path it works.

ROUTES

```
root :to => 'static#home'
get "vault", :to => "restricted_content#vault"


Refinery::Core::Engine.routes.prepend do
 get '/courses/:id/classroom', :to => 'courses/courses#classroom'
end

mount Refinery::Core::Engine, :at => '/cms'
devise_for :users
```

Comment: Can you post your routes.rb file?

Answer (score 0):

RefineryCMS needs to be mounted at root to work properly. Why is it important to mount it at `cms`?

Comment: Because it conflicts with devise.

Answer (score 0):

Read through [this issue](https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms/issues/1863) @ github. I've provided a [monkeypatch](https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms/issues/1863#issuecomment-8422729) for this issue.